TypeError: Magento\LoginAsCustomerGraphQl\Plugin\DataObjectHelperPlugin::afterPopulateWithArray()
When I tried to login the customer in the magento2, then it throws the error:
"TypeError: Magento\LoginAsCustomerGraphQl\Plugin\DataObjectHelperPlugin::afterPopulateWithArray(): Argument #2 ($result) must be of type Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper, Cminds\MultiUserAccounts\Model\Plugin\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper given, called in /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-login-as-customer-graph-ql/Plugin/DataObjectHelperPlugin.php:44"


Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\LoginAsCustomerGraphQl\Plugin\DataObjectHelperPlugin->afterPopulateWithArray()
#1 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#2 /var/www/html/protecta/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Api/DataObjectHelper/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#3 /var/www/html/protecta/app/code/Cminds/MultiUserAccounts/Model/ResourceModel/SubaccountTransportRepository.php(295): Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper\Interceptor->populateWithArray()
#4 /var/www/html/protecta/app/code/Cminds/MultiUserAccounts/Model/Plugin/Customer/AccountManagement/Plugin.php(158): Cminds\MultiUserAccounts\Model\ResourceModel\SubaccountTransportRepository->getById()
#5 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Cminds\MultiUserAccounts\Model\Plugin\Customer\AccountManagement\Plugin->afterAuthenticate()
#6 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): WEBO\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/protecta/generated/code/WEBO/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(23): WEBO\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#8 /var/www/html/protecta/app/code/WEBO/Login/Controller/Index/Loginpopuppost.php(353): WEBO\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->authenticate()
#9 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost->execute()
#10 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->___callParent()
#11 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/html/protecta/generated/code/WEBO/Login/Controller/Index/Loginpopuppost/Interceptor.php(23): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#13 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->execute()
#14 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->___callParent()
#16 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/html/protecta/generated/code/WEBO/Login/Controller/Index/Loginpopuppost/Interceptor.php(32): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#18 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): WEBO\Login\Controller\Index\Loginpopuppost\Interceptor->dispatch()
#19 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#20 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#21 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#22 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#23 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#25 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/fastly/magento2/Model/FrontControllerPlugin.php(128): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Fastly\Cdn\Model\FrontControllerPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#27 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(72): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#29 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#30 /var/www/html/protecta/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#31 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#32 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent()
#34 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-application-performance-monitor/Plugin/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor->aroundLaunch()
#36 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/html/protecta/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#38 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#39 /var/www/html/protecta/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#40 {main}


Please add full trace log.

Hey, please disable once Cminds_MultiUserAccounts module  and try.

disabling that module didnot worked.any other solutions?
